# Is this New Zealand pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation

“Our son will get that game over my dead body.” ([recorded from Korean EBS](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/414))

/ei/ in game sounds like /ii/, /ӕ/ in that /ɛ/. Consulting Wikipedia ([e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel); [ӕ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_front_unrounded_vowel)), the two vowels seem to be pronounced by someone from New Zealand. Is this correct?

Comment: That sounds like it is pronounced by an American person.

Comment: Definitely not Kiwi.  I'm with Tristan, it sounds North American to me.

Comment: Listenever, you can familiarise yourself with New Zealand English (the recording that you linked to, doesn't sound anything like it) by watching this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcgFnGnLjTc YouTube also has more videos of that programme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the pronunciations, the prosody—the contour of rises and falls in pitch, stress and quantity—is dead wrong. *My*, *dead* and *bo-* should be equally spaced and at the same levels of pitch and stress, and *body* should have a falling cadence, with full stop rather than comma intonation.

I don't believe this is a native speaker of English at all. My ear tells me her native languge is Far Eastern, but I don't know enough about languages from  your part of the world to say what cues lead me to that. The rhotic pronunciation of *our* and *over* suggest to me that she learned her English from North Americans rather than Australians or New Zealanders.

Comment: I agree with everything here. To give further evidence that she learned her English from Americans, the first vowel in *body* sounds much more American than British.